# Interesting pandas groupby confusion

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a confusion (and an interesting observation) regarding group by and sum.

I have the NBA dataset where I perform the following two independent actions

A :  df.groupby('Team')['Salary'].sum()

B :

gb1 = df.groupby(['Team','Position','College'])['Salary'].sum()

gb2 = gb1.groupby('Team')['Salary'].sum()

The output of gb2 in part B is different than the output of part A. I want to know, why is that? I think it should be same since in both the methods (A and B) I am effectively grouping by team and taking sum of salaries. Then why are they different?

Comment: you are grouping on more than ```Team``` in gb`, you have Position and College - as such, the grouping will be based on those three items.

Comment: Can you post the full setup and code youre using? Your code as you've posted it doesn't work, so it's hard for us to see what you're looking at. Pandas shouldn't work the way you describe... I expect you have a bug somewhere on your end.

Comment: your A is grouping by Team. Then in B, your gb2 does group by Team, however,  youre doing a groupby, of something you already have grouped (by Team, Position, and College). If anything, your gb1 and gb2 should be the same. But it will be different than A

Answer (score 0):

The code below tries to replicate the question. Problem could be `NaN` or other missing values in the columns `Position` and/or `College`.

The answers below from the two grouping methods `A` and `B` from question do match in this example.

- `Option # 1` and `Option # 2` below answers match.
- `Option # 3` does
  not match because of `NaN`.

However, as discussed in the comments, it is difficult to know exactly what the data looks like in the DataFrame used in the question above.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team':['A','A','B','A','B','C','C','B'],
    'Salary':[1000,2000,300,5000,200,10000,12000,100],
    'College':['c1','c1','c2','c1','c2','c3','c3','c2'],
    'Position':[1,1,2,1,2,3,3,2],
    'College2':['c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c2','c1','c2'],
    'Position2':[1,2,1,1,3,2,3,1],
    'College3':['c1','c2','c1','c1','c2','c2','c1','c2'],
    'Position3':[1,2,1,1,np.nan,2,3,1]
})
```

**Method: A**

```
# Get groupby() sum
df.groupby(['Team'])['Salary'].sum()
```

Output

```
Team
A     8000
B      600
C    22000
Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```

**Method: B**

**Option # 1**: Using columns `Position` and `College`

```
gb1 = df.groupby(['Team', 'Position','College'])['Salary'].sum().reset_index()
gb2 = gb1.groupby(['Team'])['Salary'].sum()
gb2
```

Output

```
Team
A     8000
B      600
C    22000
Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```

**Option # 2**: Using columns `Position2` and `College2`

```
gb1 = df.groupby(['Team', 'Position2','College2'])['Salary'].sum().reset_index()
gb2 = gb1.groupby(['Team'])['Salary'].sum()
gb2
```

Output

```
Team
A     8000
B      600
C    22000
Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```

**Option # 3**: Using columns `Position3` and `College3` (with NaN)

```
gb1 = df.groupby(['Team', 'Position3','College3'])['Salary'].sum().reset_index()
gb2 = gb1.groupby(['Team'])['Salary'].sum()
gb2
```

Output:

```
Team
A     8000
B      400
C    22000
Name: Salary, dtype: int64
```